# How do I convert OpenGLES shaders to Metal compatible ones?

Tags: objective-c, swift, opengl-es, metal

I have a project which uses about 2 dozen **.vsh** and **.fsh** files to draw 2D tiles using OpenGLES. Since that is deprecated, I want to convert my project to Metal. My head is now swimming with vocabulary and techniques involved in both systems - graphics is not my forte.

Can I use OpenGLES to compile the .vsh/.fsh files, and then save them in a metal-compatible format? The goal would be to then use the saved information in a metal-centric world and remove all the OpenGLES code from the project. I've spent a few days on this already, and yet I don't understand the processes enough to fully attempt the transition to Metal. Any/all help is appreciated.

I saw this: "On devices that support it, the GLSL code you provide to SKShader is automatically converted to Metal shading language and run on a Metal renderer", which leads me to believe there is a way to get this done.  I just don't know where to begin. [OpenGL ES deprecated in iOS 12 and SKShader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828497/opengl-es-deprecated-in-ios-12-and-skshader)

I have seen this:
[Convert OpenGL shader to Metal (Swift) to be used in CIFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121127/convert-opengl-shader-to-metal-swift-to-be-used-in-cifilter), and if it answers my question, I don't understand how.

I don't think this answers it either: [OpenGL ES and OpenGL compatible shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435105/opengl-es-and-opengl-compatible-shaders)

Answers/techniques can use either Objective-C or Swift - the existing code is Objective-C, the rest of the project has been converted to Swift 5.

Edit (June 20230)
Check out this amazing link, and other videos by this guy. He also has links to a GitHub demo project. It's about the fundamentals of programming with shaders (for those who are lacking the basics)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4s1h2YETNY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want:

1) You can use [MoltenGL](https://moltengl.com/moltengl/) to seamlessly convert your **GLSL** shaders to **MSL**.

2) You can use open-source shader cross-compilers like: [krafix](https://github.com/Kode/krafix), [pmfx-shader](https://github.com/polymonster/pmfx-shader), etc.

---

I would like to point out that based on my experience it would be better in terms of **performance** that you try to rewrite the shaders yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into open-source shader cross-compilers, first. If time permits, I'll then try rewriting what I have.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/aras-p/glsl-optimizer) is another cross compiler option which supports GLSL-ES to metal.

Comment: As the designer of both tools, I recommend you use the converter tool in [MoltenVK](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK), which is more robust than the converter tool in MoltenGL, and will handle GLSL in addition to GLSL-ES.